# Why recipe for target 'mykernel.bin' failed?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to create a simple mykernel.bin file using Ubuntu.

```
GPPPARAM = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exception -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -m elf_i386
objects = loader.o kernel.o

%o: %.cpp
    g++ $(GPPPARAM) -o $@ -c $<

%o: %.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin : linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)
```

the output is:

make mykernel.bin
ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o mykernel.bin loader.o kernel.o
ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `loader.o' is incompatible with i386 output
ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file`kernel.o' is incompatible with i386 output
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'mykernel.bin' failed
make: *** [mykernel.bin] Error 1

Comment: If you have a question, please ask it.  Include the command you invoked, the output you got, and why you didn't expect that output.  Just looking at your makefile I can see that it's wrong: `%o : %.cpp` should be `%.o: %.cpp` (note period between `%` and `o`).

Comment: ld -m elf_i386 -T linker.ld -o mykernel.bin loader.o kernel.o
ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `loader.o' is incompatible with i386 output
ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `kernel.o' is incompatible with i386 output
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'mykernel.bin' failed
make: *** [mykernel.bin] Error 1

Comment: Please edit your question and put the information there, where it can be properly formatted, rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to show the complete output, including the compile lines for your object files, then it would be clear that your compiler flags are not being used to compile your source code.  As a result, the object files being generated are for your native operating system which is most likely 64bit, when you want 32bit.

The reason for this is as I described above: your pattern rule is wrong.  You have written `%o : %.cpp` when you wanted to write `%.o : %.cpp`.  The pattern rule you've written tells make that if it wants to build a file `loader.o` (so the stem of the pattern `%o` matches `loader.`) it can do so by compiling a file `loader..cpp` (because the pattern character `%` in `%.cpp` is replaced with the stem `loader.`).  Since there's no `loader..cpp` file, your pattern is discarded as not matching and make proceeds to look for another pattern and it finds one, as a built-in rule.

But since you are using non-standard variable names `GPPPARAM` instead of the standard `CXXFLAGS`, none of your flags are used by the default rule.

You have two choices: you can either fix your pattern rules so they're correct:

```
%.o: %.cpp
        g++ $(GPPPARAM) -o $@ -c $<

%.o: %.s
        as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<
```

Or you can get rid of your own pattern rules and use make's built-in rules, and set the standard variables to ensure your options are used:

```
CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exception -fno-leading-underscore

AS := as
ASFLAGS := --32
```